# Access VBA code : How to define multiple WHERE statements ? UPDATE - SET - WHERE statement

Tags: ms-access, vba, sql-update, where-clause

I got following code to work, except for the last line.

So I want to update a table called loggingX , this is working with the code below, except for I want the WHERE clause to not only check for 1 field (this is working) , but I want the WHERE to also check for field WHid to be a fixed value.

I would like to know how I can add multiple parts to my WHERE statement here. UPDATE should only be done if these 2 conditions below are met. I only have trouble and want to know how to put both conditions in the WHERE clause.

```
stdid=" & Me.txtID.Tag
WHid=" & Me.txtWHid
```

Complete update statement for current DB (AND is not working):

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE loggingX " & _
    " SET stdid=" & Me.txtID & _
    ", stdname='" & Me.txtName & "'" & _
    ", gender='" & Me.cboGender & "'" & _
    ", phone='" & Me.txtPhone & "'" & _
    ", address='" & Me.txtAddress & "'" & _
    ", WHid='" & Me.txtWHid & "'" & _
    " WHERE stdid=" & Me.txtID.Tag
    " AND WHid=" & Me.txtWHid
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an ampersand and underscore on the second to last line:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE loggingX " & _
    " SET stdid=" & Me.txtID & _
    ", stdname='" & Me.txtName & "'" & _
    ", gender='" & Me.cboGender & "'" & _
    ", phone='" & Me.txtPhone & "'" & _
    ", address='" & Me.txtAddress & "'" & _
    ", WHid='" & Me.txtWHid & "'" & _
    " WHERE stdid=" & Me.txtID.Tag & _
    " AND WHid=" & Me.txtWHid
```